# Use if statement to detect if user entered specific character or number

Tags: c, function, char, type-conversion, int

In my getInput function I am scanning input from the user.

If the user enters `'q'` or `'Q'` I want to print that the user wishes to exit (the program doesn't have to actually 'exit' in technical terms).

If the user enters any other value, I want to return that value and continue running my program.

So, my question is:

How can I test for a certain character value int-to-char conversion similar to how I've attempted it below?

My program exits if the user enters a character and runs if the user enters an integer, but doesn't properly detect that `'q'` or `'Q'` has been pressed.

This is the code I have so far:

```
int getInput() {

  int numSets;
  char quitTest1 = 'q';
  char quitTest2 = 'Q';

  //get number of sets from user
  printf("\nEnter desired amount of random number sets (or 'q'/'Q' to quit): ");
  scanf("%d", &numSets);

  if (numSets == (int)quitTest1 || numSets == (int)quitTest2) {
    printf("Exited");
  }

  else {
    return numSets;
  }

}
```

I'm probably missing some major principle but I can't seem to find much help on Google.

All answers are appreciated.

Comment: You have described what you are trying to do but you have forgotten to ask a question.  Please edit your question so that it asks something specific!

Comment: Have you tried printing `numSets` to check that you are doing what you think you're doing ?

Comment: Note that `int result = scanf("%d", &numSets);` will return 0 if it fails to read an integer.  At that point you could elect to attempt reading a character instead.  Alternatively you could abandon this whole approach and read a string using `fgets` and then parse that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that

```
scanf("%d", &numSets);
```

Will not assign any value to `numSets` if input is a character, `numSets` will maintain its previous value, which in this case is unknown since the variable is uninitialized, using it ahead will cause undefined behaviour.

Getting the input as a `char array` an convert to `char` or `int` seems the best option.

[**Live sample here**](https://onlinegdb.com/B1dK2ywrI)

```
int getInput() {

    char numSets[100];
    int number = -1;
    char q;
    char quitTest1 = 'q';
    char quitTest2 = 'Q';

    //get number of sets from user
    printf("\nEnter desired amount of random number sets (or 'q'/'Q' to quit): ");
    fgets(numSets, sizeof(numSets), stdin);
    if (sscanf(numSets, "%d", &number)){
        printf("%d", number); //testing
        return number;
    } 

    if (sscanf(numSets, "%c", &q) && (q == quitTest1 || q == quitTest2))
        printf("Exited");
    else{
        puts("Invalid input");

    return number; //will return -1;
}
```